# Accidentally changed shell in gnome-terminal, no longer opens

Tags: gnome, bash, 15.04, gnome-terminal

I wanted to make `screenfetch` start at terminal startup.

But I realized that I changed the shell from bash to `screenfetch` and of course gnome terminal doesn't startup.

I have installed MATE terminal just so I can use a terminal. But I want to use the gnome terminal

So any configurations I can remove or anything?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: 15.04; gnome-shell 3.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Start the application and navigate to

```
org.gnome.terminal.legacy
```

Open the category `profiles:` and select the wrong profile, or check all profiles.

In the right hand pane you will see a key <kbd>custom-command</kbd>. Remove the value or use the Button <kbd>Set to Default</kbd> in the lower pane.

[image]

Comment: there isn't any "Settings" inside of legacy?

Comment: yeah, i fixed it, thanks! (it was inside of profile and a long string of letters/numbers and i pressed default) sorry for not reading everything.

Comment: @KimAndré Don't thank me! ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...

Comment: there. liked and accepted.

Answer (score -2):

Try running this in MATE:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-terminal; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

This will uninstall and purge the configs, then reinstall the latest version.

Comment: Changing the shell is part of the user configuration. Therefore your commands are useless.

Comment: If so, then the MATE default shell would be changed as well, right?

Comment: No, the mate-terminal and the gnome-terminal have different configurations.

Comment: MATE isn't changed, the commands you gave me sadly didn't work.

Comment: "Profile Preferences"

Comment: Give the output of 'ls -a $HOME'

Comment: Or the output of 'ls -a /home/username/'

Comment: .
..
.apport-ignore.xml
.atlauncher
ATLauncher
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
.cache
Colossal Order
.config
.dbus
Desktop
Documents
.dolphin-emu
Downloads
Emulation
forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1492-1.7.10-installer.jar.log
ftb
.ftblauncher
Games
.gconf
.gimp-2.8
girls boobs
.gksu.lock
.gnome
.gnupg
.gvfs
.gyazo.id
.ICEauthority
.java
.local
.minecraft
.mono
.mozilla
Music
My Games
.nv
.nvidia-settings-rc
.openvr
Pictures
.pki
.PlayOnLinux
PlayOnLinux's virtual drives
Popcorn Time
.profile
Public
.pulse-cookie
.PyCharm40
PycharmProjects

Comment: Smith Micro
.snes9x
.ssh
.steam
.steampath
.steampid
.sudo_as_admin_successfulTemplates
terminal-settings.bak
Videos
.wine
.zsnes

Comment: You'll need to fine the config file itself.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: It's probably inside ~/.gnome/ somewhere.